# How do I save a historical (past) dataset in Foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I want to save a version of my dataset called (order_clean). But not the current version. The version I want to save is from the past. I understand this is a historical transaction that still exists within my retention policy window. How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via an API call and hitting a specific endpoint.
This answer assumes a working knowledge around authorization tokens and curl requests:

1. Obtain the desired dataset’s RID (Example in screenshot below), as well as the transaction ID of the transaction corresponding to the version of the dataset you want.
   [[image: Dataset order_clean]
2. Create a new branch in your specific dataset by running a curl request populated as follows:

   `curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN" "STACK_URL/foundry-catalog/api/catalog/datasets/YOUR_DATASET_RID/branchesUnrestricted2/NEW_BRANCH_NAME" -d '{"parentRef": "YOUR_TRANSACTION_ID", "parentBranchId": "master"}'`
3. Replace `YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN, STACK_URL, YOUR_DATASET_RID, NEW_BRANCH_NAME` and `YOUR_TRANSACTION_ID` with appropriate values. Short lived authentication token can be generated [following these instructions](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/platform-security-third-party/user-generated-tokens/#generation).
4. Save the branch into a new dataset with a transform in a Code Repo, specifying the Input with the path to the dataset as well as the new branch’s name from #2.